# Combined Select and Filter MS-Graph query parameters not working as expected for signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

```
Query: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,displayName,signInActivity&$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2020-03-01T00:00:00Z
```

I am trying to query for users based on "lastSignInDateTime". When I do this , the response gives all the properties for every user returned. I then try to reduce this response by adding a "select" parameter to reduce the properties returned but it seems to have no effect. Is it possible to combine the "Filter" and "Select" query Parameter's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a bug for collection enumeration in that beta endpoint. Due to be fixed within next couple of months. AS a workaround you can export your dataset into data structure and filter in memory (preferred) or you can query specific users (expensive and not recommended)